# Left join with Dplyr bringing just 1 field form the other table

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

My problem is that I would like to do a left join with dplyr like this:

```
x <- left.join(TableA, TableB)
```

How can I do to bring just a specific field from TableB? Imagine TableB has 3 fields x,y,z and I just want x in TableA

Comment: What field do you want to match the two tables on? Use use `select()` to keep only the columns for joining and whatever columns you want to merge in. It would be easier to help with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can use `select` to keep only those vars in `TableB` first: 
`x <- TableA %>% left_join(select(TableB, id, x), by = "id")`

Comment: but in the example that you said "id" is the common var in each table to join the two tables, What I want to do is... imagine TableA containds the vars "id" and "euros", TableB has "id" - "city" - "country". What I want to do is bring city(which is on tableB) to tableA but only that field not "country " for exameple.

Answer (score 41):

To join both tables as desired, you have to select field `x` and an id-field from `TableB` for the join. You can do this with the `select()` function.
Let's assume for the join that your id-field in `TableB` is `y`.

```
x <- TableA %>% 
  left_join(select(TableB, x, y), by = c("id" = "y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You subset TableB first. So you do something like:

```
TableB <- TableB[,'x,']

left_join(TableA,TableB)
```

The obvious disadvantage of this method is that we are bound to join with column x. Suppose you want to join with column y but want only x in the end result, then you can do the following:

```
select(left_join(TableA,TableB, by = 'y'), -c(y,z))
```

Answer (score -2):

x <- TableA %>% left_join(select(TableB, id), by.x = "id")

Comment: That joins all fields in tableB to tableA by "id". I want to join just one var from tableB to tableA :) Thanks!